# Unable to login to main pc(server) in serva pxe boot

Tags: pxe

I can not pass from here it

[image]

Unable to login here. It says invalid password of network name not found i tried everything, But I am unable to pass from it

Comment: Do you know that the credentials you are using are valid for the server?

Answer (score 4):

Two possibilities:

1. Invalid Password:

   This problem is usually seen when the **WIA_WDS_SHARE** is not properly created.
   You create **WIA_WDS_SHARE** at Serva's PC; that share must grant minimally reading rights to some Serva's PC "user" identified by its **username** and **password**. You cannot use a username with no password here.
   Those are the username and password required by ServaPENet.

   On very rare occasions the problem could be also triggered by a malfunctioning NIC driver. You have to check this too.
2. Network Name not Found:

   This sometimes happens on back-to-back situations where the booting client is unable to find the **WIA_WDS_SHARE**. You can solve this by turning on the WINS service on Serva's PC or you can alternative try just adding the wins DHCP option (44) to Serva.

   ```
   44|192.168.1.1
   ```

   where 192.168.1.1 is Serva's IP

For more info you should carefully read [this link](http://vercot.com/%7Eserva/an/WindowsPXE1.html#troubleshooting).

Answer (score 1):

For me I had to explictly share the WIA_WDS folder as WIA_WDS_SHARE, that is select that folder specifically. Go to properties - share - change share name - accept. If you can't change the share name you may need to unshare the folder and share it again.

Answer (score -1):

The error 0x56 also originates by putting a wrong username. In the folder WIA_WDS_SHARE, you must give the security option, and in this it appears the real name of the user, which must be placed in the client computer with the password of the corresponding user.

Comment: Why are you referring to “error 0x56”?  It wasn’t mentioned in the question.  Do you mean that the “invalid password or network name not found” error *message* can also be caused by specifying a wrong username?  Can you back that up with a reference? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.